# Problem booting to Windows 10 after Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS install

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, windows

A friend of mine gave me his old laptop. HP Probook 470. Only the harddrive was missing so I used an old one I had lying around. Installed windows 10, may update, on one part of the drive and Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on the other part. However, after install, the machine did not want to boot back to Windows. I tried the tool Bootrepair (the log it created for forum support is located at: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tM5GWZHN8H/ ) and I tried the Windows 10 boot repair option via booting from the USB install disc. That one came up empty completely. Bootrepair tried something but did not fix it the way I would like it to boot. It shows the grub2 bootmenu and it boots to Ubuntu just fine, it also shows the listing of Windows 10 but when I try to boot to it, it just stays silent/black for a bit and then returns me to the GRUB2 boot screen. Or maybe it reboots and brings me back to the GRUB2 boot screen.

I'll be using Ubuntu mostly, luckily. It just is a joy and gives me some new stuff to learn, I was a bit done with Windows. Not that I know everything of course but getting the hang of Ubuntu, at least the basics and be grounded solidly in it, is something I'd like to build up.

Anyway, anyone that can help me out? I would like to keep the GRUB2 bootloader appear and then have me choose for an Ubuntu or Windows 10 boot.

Usually I fiddle about a bit more myself but since I am on a very very slow internet connection, I'd to ruin one of the installs by fiddling about too much and having to wait 4 hours to download all updates again during or after install of Ubuntu/Windows combined. Combined it took eight hours today, so... any help is greatly appreciated!

Fastboot in BIOS is off. SecureBoot is off also.
The custom.cfg file as per suggested topic did not change anything.
I ran bootinfoscript as also suggested in that topic and pasted the results here: https://pastebin.com/AqBFZCY1
Still more info can be found in the log Bootrepair created, which I have posted here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tM5GWZHN8H/

The command `sudo efibootmgr -v` churns out:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,7e1637ff-8170-4529-8772-cfc613801cce,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7e1637ff-8170-4529-8772-cfc613801cce,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows and that typically means Windows fast start up must be off. Boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu & turn fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

I ran boot-repair again. Then it booted straight into windows. It could boot into Ubuntu via F9/UEFI Boot Menu but by default it booted into Windows. So that was step 1. In Windows I set the bootmanager via bcdedit to use the correct EFI file via an administrative command prompt and then typed:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

This completed succesfully. After restart, the GRUB2 bootloader appeared again and I could boot Ubuntu and/or Windows the way it is supposed to work.

I enabled FastBoot again, first. Which worked out. Next, I enabled SecureBoot also.

Both operating systems run fine again. Hope this will help someone else in the future too.